# Relocate MySQL to a dropbox location

Tags: mysql, xampp, dropbox

By default MySQL is installed to C:\xampp\MySQL.

Is it possible to set it to a new generic location such as C:\Dropbox\MySQL?

I'd like to create a shared location, so I can keep my tables in a single location, while accessing from my different machines (albeit not at the same time of course). I'm looking for some kind of config, outside of C:\xampp\MySQL that points to it. I'm assuming that this is the place where I can relocate to the new location.

Comment: Are you intending to use Dropbox to share tables?

Comment: I'd like to try to. Obviously not at the same time

Comment: Theoretically you could do it. Read the info how to change your data paths in the answer below. I suspect that you could run into issues with data corruption depending how files are locked and how and when Dropbox tries to copy them. Dropbox was never designed for that sort of use case.

Comment: Interesting, I'm only really interested in using DB as a place of common storage. You comment makes me think that if I were to keep my current machine off line to DB while working on it, putting it online again to update the finished session, that I might not run into data corruption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to change your mysql data path to any path you like.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_datadir

You can simply add the flag each time you start mysqld, or you could add it to the [mysqld] section of your user-wide/machine-wide mysql config file.

Of course, you'll have to initialize the tables first, using the mysql_install_db script ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-install-db.html )